# Can you help me solve this inequality $ \frac {(x-1)^2 (x+1)^3} {x^4 (x-2)} \le 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Help me solve this inequality:
$$\frac {(x-1)^2 (x+1)^3} {x^4 (x-2)} \le 0$$

Comment: You must figure out whether each factor is positive or negative.  And for the whole thing to be negative you need a odd number of negative factors.$(x-1)^2 > 0$ and $x^4>0$  one of $(x+1)<0$ or $(x-2)<0$ but not both.  Furthermore, you cannot divide by $0.$

Comment: Got it thanks Doug!

Comment: @user457481 Hello again:  Start to contribute some of your own efforts to the questions you ask; over the past five days, and at least three questions you've asked, all you have done is beg for help to solve/answer a problem statement question you've not put any effort into.  This is not a "do my homework for me" site.

Comment: Uh I do not mean to use it as a homework site...but how exactly can I contribute to my own questions?

Comment: And given my very little knowledge of mathematics...how can I contribute to the site?

Comment: When you post a question, say where it is from.  If it is homework that is fine, just say this is my homework problem....but don't just leave it there.  Tell us what you have tried.  What you think you might need to do?  Why might that not be working?  Where do you seem to be stuck?  Then we can help you to navigate to the other side of the sticking points.

Comment: I'm new at Stack Exchange, and will keep that in mind next time onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(x-1)^{ 2 }\ge 0$ and $\quad x=1$ is solution,${ x }^{ 4 }>0$ and $x\neq 0$,$(x+1)^{ 2 }\ge 0$ and $x=-1$ is solution ,taking into considerition all of these we get 
$$\frac { (x-1)^{ 2 }(x+1)^{ 3 } }{ x^{ 4 }(x-2) } \le 0\quad \Rightarrow \frac { (x-1)^{ 2 }(x+1)^{ 2 }\left( x+1 \right)  }{ x^{ 4 }(x-2) } \le 0\quad \Rightarrow \frac { x+1 }{ x-2 } \le 0$$ now multplying both sides to $x-2$ we get
$$\frac { \left( x+1 \right) \left( x-2 \right)  }{ { \left( x-2 \right)  }^{ 2 } } \le 0\\ $$ here ${ \left( x-2 \right)  }^{ 2 }>0$ and soltion should be $x\neq 2$ $$\left( x+1 \right) \left( x-2 \right) \le 0\quad \Rightarrow \quad -1\le x<2$$ finally we get $$-1\le x<0\quad \cup \quad 0<x<2$$

Answer (score 1):

Just write the answer:
$-1\leq x<0$ or $0<x<2$

It's the intervals method.

Comment: I had applied Method of Intervals and took -1,1,2 as critical points. On experimenting , I obtained x as $(-\infinity , -1) , (1,2)$

Comment: Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: @user457481 By the intervals method if a degree of number from $\{-1,0,1,2\}$ is odd then the sign is changed, while if the degree is even then the sign is not changed. $1$ and $0$ are even degree, $2$ and $-1$ are odd degree, which gives signs of intervals: +---+

Comment: Degree of a number??

Comment: @user457481 In the expression $(x-a)^k$ the number $k$ is a degree of number $a$.

Comment: Isn't  method of intervals the one which states that ' every interval of solution must have its adjoining not being a solution and vice versa'

Comment: @user457481 It's very useful method! I am ready explain if you wish.

Comment: Don't all the 4 numbers (1,0,-1,2) have degree 1 , odd?

Comment: Yes sir please do!

Comment: @user457481' You need to draw a $x$ - axis and to put there points: $-1$, $0$, $1$ and $2$. Now, it's obvious that the sign of our function on $(2,+\infty)$ is $+$. Since the degree of $2$ is odd, then the sign changed and the sing on $(1,2)$ is $-$. Now, since the degree of $1$ is even, the sing is not changed and the sign on $(0,1)$ is still $-$.... we have the following sequence of signs: $+$, $-$, $-$, $-$,$+$ and we can wright the answer.

Comment: Almost got you... But don't all the above numbers have an odd sign on them??

Comment: @user457481 Signs of numbers are not relevant. Sign of the function on intervals is relevant.

Comment: Sign of function on intervals?

Comment: @user457481 Yes! We get the following sings: $+$, $-$, $-$, $-$, $+$ and we can write the answer immediately!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61251/discussion-between-michael-rozenberg-and-user457481).

Comment: Okay just one last thing...how do you determine degree of a number , whether it is odd or even? Don't all the above mentioned numbers have an odd degree (1)?

Comment: @user457481 In our expression we see $(x+1)^3$, which says that the degree of $-1$ is $3$ and it's an odd number. We see $(x-1)^2$, which says that the degree of $1$ is $2$ and it's even. $x^4$ says that degree of $0$ is $4$, $x-2$ says that the degree of $2$ is $1$ because $x-2=(x-2)^1$.

Comment: Ohh well explained thanks a million for your time Michael 

Comment: @user457481 You are welcome! It's very hard to explain this method on the internet. But if you indeed understood me, you can write the answer immediately. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $(x-1)^2$ and $x^4$ are  positive forall $ x\in \mathbb R$ you have to consider the two cases:

> 1. $(x+1)<0$ and $x-2 >0$
> 2. $(x+1)\geq 0$ and $x-2 <0$

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch:**

When defined, i.e. on $\mathbf R\setminus\{0,2\}$, it has the sign of $(x+1)(x-2)$. This is a quadratic polynomial, and it is negative between its roots. Hence the solutions are 
$$[-1,0)\cup(0,2)$$

Comment: Sorry Bernard I didn't get it, could explain it in a simpler way?

Comment: It was only a sketch, I know. In my opinion, it's as simple (and short) as possible, but one must have couple of facts in mind: 1) I ruled out all the even powers, which can't change the sign of the rest since they're non-negative 2) the sign of a quotient is the same as the sign of the product.  All this is but the application of the rule of  signs. Last ingredient, but it's mentioned in the answer:  a theorem on the sign of a quadratic polynomial asserts  it has the sign of its leading coefficient, except between its roots, if any. Between the roots, it has the opposite sign. Is it clearer?

Comment: Forgive me I'm new to inequalities....didn't get the part after 'theorem on the signs of quadratic polynomial'..

Comment: And why did you rule out terms with a positive power? Just because they cannot yield a negative number, we can just rule them out if the equation? Does it not impact the answer?

Comment: Didn't you see it in high school? It asserts that if $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ has real roots $\alpha$ and ˆ$\beta$, then $p(x)$ has the sign of $a$ on $(-\infty,\alpha)\cup(\beta,+\infty)$, and the opposite sign on $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: Yes I ruled even powers out because they can't yield a negative number. As far as the sign is concerned it doesn't impact the answer *by the rule of signs*.